# illegal multibyte sequence in Pycharm while using exec(open('file.py').read())

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, decode, gbk

I'm using PyCharm to run code:

```
exec(open('file.py').read())
```

while running some file I got:

**UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0xa7 in position 2655: illegal multibyte sequence**

Any friend can help?

Comment: If the file does not contain valid unicode, it should be opened with binary indicator.

Comment: Thanks,I have this:# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

Comment: The question is not, what the file states it is, but how the editor was configured, which wrote it. These seem not to match. An `\xA7` should be easy to find...

Comment: In text mode, if encoding is not specified the encoding used is platform dependent: `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` is called to get the current locale encoding. Use `open('file.py', encoding='utf-8-sig')`